# Unable to synchronise with a remote peer

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, peers

I am running a private network with two geth instances one on my machine and other on an AWS server using the same Genesis file. I am also using a networkid flag to differentiate my private network.

**I have successfully added the two nodes as PEERS using a static-nodes.json file** - which I confirm through the `admin.peers` function.

Now i started mining on the remote node and mined some blocks and then stopped the miner. Now, my local geth instance starts to synchronise and just as it does, I get the following error

> **########## BAD BLOCK #########**
>   **Chain config: {ChainID: 0 Homestead:  DAO:  DAOSupport: false EIP150:  EIP155:  EIP158: }**
>
> **Number: 1
>   Hash: 0xfc5d907f90c021e55b4ffceb27413992e722cbfa63cc77aed9274938a903f22d**
>
> **Error: invalid merkle root (remote: 70d1206c41e2508d61a0b6e605e5d26a93b94fdf48ea6e781d410ea269bf6b44 local: 08c6e61d54f29af09d3f063157f75dbdc3121b311d471ef19523a86c80b51e09)**

I have been getting this issue for a day , even when i have previously been able to synchronise some peers on a private network.

1. **Is there something wrong with the Chain config object ?**
2. **I have even tried removing the chaindata folder and this issue still persists.**

Comment: Are you using same `genesis` file on both nodes?

Comment: yes, i am using the same genesis file and i have successfully added the both geth nodes as peers.