# Synchronisation issue on Mainnet, testnet and private network

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, synchronization

I am just unable to synchronise on any kind of network either main network , testnet and not even on private network.

I have updated my geth instance to a newer version - Geth/v1.5.9-stable-a07539fb/linux/go1.7.3.

I used the following command for the testnet as well as the mainnet - **geth --fast --cache=512 console** and with --testnet flag too , but kept getting the following errors -

1. Synchronisation failed: receipt download canceled (requested
2. Synchronisation failed: block body download canceled (requested)
3. Synchronisation failed: state data download canceled (requested)

And as a result when i use `eth.blockNumber` in the geth Javascript console, it returns `0`.

Also i am facing error in syncing of a private testnet as given in this link [Synchronisation issue on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/unable-to-synchronise-with-a-remote-peer) -

How can i solve the synchronisation issues ?

EDIT - I just noticed that the `currentBlock` value is increasing when i see the output of `eth.syncing`. So should `eth.blockNumber` returning 0 be an issue ?